# MATLAB: isequal in conjunction with tables

Tags: matlab, equality, cell-array

I am trying to determine equality for two tables. Usually, `isequal` should work with tables. However, when one of the tables to compare is the content of a cell, then I receive an unexpected result. Take a look at this:

```
a{1} = table(1,2,3);
b = a{1};

isequal(a,b)
```

Why is the result `false`? I would expect the tables to be equal (result `true`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

A cell is not the same as its contents. Try

```
isequal(a{1},b)
```

## Long answer

To clarify:

- `a` is a 1×1 cell array
- `a(1)` is its first cell. In this case this is the same as `a`,  because `a` is 1×1.
- `a{1}` is the *contents* of the first cell, namely a table.

So `isequal(a{1},b)` gives `true` because it compares two tables, and those tables are indeed equal.

On other hand, `isequal(a,b)` gives `false` because `a` is a cell containing a table and `b` is a table.

Note also that

```
isequal(a,{b})
```

would give `true`, because `a` is a 1×1 cell array containing table `b`, and `{b}` is that table packed into a 1×1 cell cell array, so it is the same.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Your short answer is telling me enough. What a stupid mistake. Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: @Andi No problem! The explanation may be useful to other people

Comment: +1 Nice answer. Quick insight via short answer, yet nice helpful description in the long. This is a model answer.